# CodeIgniter Pagination Without Page Numbers

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I need help
I am trying to create CodeIgniter pagination without using page numbers in it, just like:

> |**< Previous Page**| |**Next Page >**|

but I don't find any tutorial, and mostly using page numbers in it. Anyone can share the code or maybe some helpful tips?
Thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the configuration during initialize:

```
$config['display_pages'] = FALSE;
```

[View CI Pagination Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#hiding-the-pages).